# Problem with stopping rotating items around a circle with CSS and jQuery on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to stop the animation of rotating items around a circle whenever i hover over an item.
From the **codepen** i got from [this link by Amarnath](https://codepen.io/aroganz/pen/GRRrwzx), the item that is being hovered over stops rotating but the other items continue to rotate or spin in reversed direction. *My goal is to make all the items stop rotating whenever one of them is being hovered over*.
I would appreciate any help.
Thanks

```js
var radius = 100; // adjust to move out items in and out 
var fields = $('.item'),
  container = $('#container'),
  width = container.width(),
  height = container.height();
var angle = 0,
  step = (2 * Math.PI) / fields.length;
fields.each(function() {
  var x = Math.round(width / 2 + radius * Math.cos(angle) - $(this).width() / 2);
  var y = Math.round(height / 2 + radius * Math.sin(angle) - $(this).height() / 2);
  if (window.console) {
    console.log($(this).text(), x, y);
  }
  $(this).css({
    left: x + 'px',
    top: y + 'px'
  });
  angle += step;
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
}

#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: spin 20s linear infinite;
}

.item {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #f00;
  animation: spin 20s linear infinite reverse;
}

.item:nth-child(1):hover {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}

#container:hover,
.item:hover {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item"><a href="www.colorchalk.com">4</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pause the animation of the `.item` element whenever you hover over the container with the following selector:

```
#container:hover .item
```

This selects all `.item` elements when the `#container` is hovered upon.

```js
var radius = 100; // adjust to move out items in and out 
var fields = $('.item'),
  container = $('#container'),
  width = container.width(),
  height = container.height();
var angle = 0,
  step = (2 * Math.PI) / fields.length;
fields.each(function() {
  var x = Math.round(width / 2 + radius * Math.cos(angle) - $(this).width() / 2);
  var y = Math.round(height / 2 + radius * Math.sin(angle) - $(this).height() / 2);
  
  $(this).css({
    left: x + 'px',
    top: y + 'px'
  });
  angle += step;
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
}

#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: spin 20s linear infinite;
}

.item {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #f00;
  animation: spin 20s linear infinite reverse;
}

.item:nth-child(1):hover {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}

#container:hover,
#container:hover .item {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item"><a href="www.colorchalk.com">4</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow this is so awesome, i never thought about using the container to stop everything.Appreciate a lot mate.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var radius = 100; // adjust to move out items in and out 
var fields = $('.item'),
  container = $('#container'),
  width = container.width(),
  height = container.height();
var angle = 0,
  step = (2 * Math.PI) / fields.length;
fields.each(function() {
  var x = Math.round(width / 2 + radius * Math.cos(angle) - $(this).width() / 2);
  var y = Math.round(height / 2 + radius * Math.sin(angle) - $(this).height() / 2);
  
  $(this).css({
    left: x + 'px',
    top: y + 'px'
  });
  angle += step;
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
}

#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: spin 20s linear infinite;
}

.item {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #f00;
  animation: spin 20s linear infinite reverse;
}

.item:nth-child(1):hover {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}

#container:hover,
#container:hover .item {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item"><a href="www.colorchalk.com">4</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).